# Prevent Category Pages from Generating

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have a website that is generating /category pages and /taxonomy archive type pages, with a list of posts containing a certain taxonomy term.  I do not have a template for this page and they seem unnecessary/duplicate content.  Is there any way to prevent them from being created?

category/region/all/boston?page=2&region=DEFAULT
/taxonomy/term/14/”?page=19&region=DEFAULT

link to one of these pages
http://nyc.thedelimagazine.com/taxonomy/term/14/%E2%80%9D?page=19&region=DEFAULT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *really* want to prevent the URLs from existing at all, you could probably unset the paths using a [hook_menu_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7). I would be careful with that though, as it might have unforseen consequences. The creating module may in some way depend on the paths existance.

I don't know where the category paths comes from but I guess the answer will be the same as for the taxonomy ones.

My solution would be to take over the URL with [Page manager](http://drupal.org/project/ctools), and simply pass the user a redirect to the front page. (Or a 404, if you prefer).
Note that I'm talking about "Page manager" in Ctools, *not* Panels. The two modules are often confused and their names interchanged.

Comment: I already created a module using hook_nodeapi for 301 redirects given certain cases for different urls. should I just add a new case to this instead of installing another module?  Where are these pages stored in the database, I was trying to keep them from being created and complicating the site.

Comment: If you already have a hook_nodeapi, then it's easy to stick with that. I could make a case for PM anyway, but I think that's out of scope. Only the "root" path is stored, such as "taxonomy/term/", the arguments specific paths such as "taxonomy/term/14" is created on the fly. Try a query like: "SELECT * FROM menu_router WHERE path LIKE "taxonomy/term/%";" and you'll find them. These are the entries you can prevent from showing up with hook_menu_alter.

Comment: thanks, I think I will do:    if (arg(0)== 'taxonomy')   { drupal_goto()}